# ErrorException when installing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

When tried to install using :

```
composer require "arcanedev/log-viewer:~3.0"
```

I got :

> [ErrorException]
>         Declaration of Arcanedev\LogViewer\LogViewerServiceProvider::registerConfig() should
>   be compatible with
>   Arcanedev\Support\PackageServiceProvider::registerConfig($separator =
>   '.')

Any idea?

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework Boilerplate Project.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "boilerplate"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html" : "5.*",
        "laravel/socialite" : "~2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "1.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "3.*",
        "fortawesome/font-awesome": "4.*",
        "hieu-le/active": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "laracasts/utilities": "~2.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "~3.4",

      "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.0.0",
      "vivify-ideas/admin-panel-generator": "dev-master",
      "witty/laravel-db-backup": "dev-master",
      "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "~1.1",
        "potsky/laravel-localization-helpers" : "~1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Performing `composer require "arcanedev/log-viewer:~3.0"` on a fresh Laravel 5 project works fine. Please post your complete `composer.json`.

Comment: please check composer.json above

Comment: you already have a newer version installed `"arcanedev/log-viewer": "~3.4",` than the one you are tying to require.